# Minimum number of edges for a tree that joins the $27$ nodes of a $3 \times 3 \times 3$ regular grid

Tags: graph-theory, upper-lower-bounds, trees, discrete-optimization, open-problem

In 2014, Dumitrescu and Tóth (see [Covering Grids by Trees](https://www.cccg.ca/proceedings/2014/papers/paper45.pdf), Figure 2) proved the existence of an inside-the-box tree consisting of $13$ connected line segments covering all the $27$ nodes of the regular grid $G_{3}^3:=\{\{0,1,2\} \times \{0,1,2\} \times \{0,1,2\}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Now, in recent years, I showed that the mentioned configuration is not optimal as we remove the constraint to solve the problem inside the box (i.e., without letting any segment of the covering tree go outside the AABB $[0,2]\times[0,2]\times[0,2]$).
My constructive proof of the existence of a tree covering $G_{3}^3$ with no more than $12$ line segments is shown below.

[image]

**Question**: Is my solution optimal or we can do even better for the given problem?

---

Update: Following Joriki's request in the comments, let me properly describe the whole tree shown in the Figure.

RED: $\{\overline{(0,0,0)-(0,4,0)} \cup \overline{(0,4,0)-(2,0,2)}\}$.

BLUE: $\{\overline{(0,0,1)-(0,2,1)} \cup \overline{(0,1,1)-(2,1,1)} \cup \overline{(2,0,1)-(2,2,1)} \cup \overline{(2,1,0)-(2,1,2)}\}$.

GREEN: $\{\overline{(1,2,0)-(1,0,0)} \cup \overline{(1,0,0)-(2,2,2)}\}$.

PINK: $\{\overline{(1,0,2)-(1,2,2)} \cup \overline{(1,2,2)-(2,0,0)}\}$.

GOLD: $\{\overline{(0,2,2)-(0,-2,2)} \cup \overline{(0,-2,2)-(2,2,0)}\}$.

Then, there are three intersection points and they are located at:
[RED $\cap$ PINK] $=\left(\frac{4}{3},\frac{4}{3},\frac{4}{3} \right)$;
[GREEN $\cap$ BLUE $\cap$ PINK] $=\left(\frac{3}{2},1,1 \right)$;
[GREEN $\cap$ GOLD] $=\left(\frac{4}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3} \right)$.

Comment: Could you explain where the components with different colours meet to form a tree?

Comment: Which of the three intersection points is not clear enough from the picture? Should I write down also the endpoints of the whole tree?

Comment: Coordinates added.

Comment: **Important note:** The linked reference shows a tree consisting of 13 "*line segments*, where each segment is either a single edge or a sequence of collinear edges." The tree has at least 17 edges. You should make it clear that you are likewise counting these line segments, not individual edges.

Comment: Fine, about the existence of a tree with only $13$ edges, just take my solution for the general $3 \times 3 \times \cdots \times 3$ points problem (i.e., the clockwise-algorithm) that returns a polygonal chain with $\frac{3^k-1}{2}$ links that joins all the $3^k$ nodes of $G_{3}^k$ for any positive integer $s$. About the problem of finding a tree with length smaller than $\frac{3^k-1}{2}$ for every $k>2$, let us define the length of a tree as the number of its line segments so that our goal is to minimize the number of those line segments.

Comment: About the mentioned clockwise-algorithm, a video animation is also available on YouTube (I can share the link if somebody is interested), but I mentioned it here for the only reason to state that we already have trails of optimal length $\frac{3^k-1}{2}$ for any given grid $G_{3}^k:=\{\{0,1,2\} \times \{0,1,2\} \times \cdots  \times \{0,1,2\}\}$ belonging to $\mathbb{R}^k$.